# NN validation error decreases and becomes constant after a while. What does that mean?

Tags: neural-network

[image]

I am using DNN with dropout(0.75), Adam, Relu. Is this overfitting or model gone haywire? Is using the model before it went haywire a good idea?

Model is 4 hidden layer(1024), input size is 8192. Data is feature extracted from image for classification. Cant give more detail on data.

Comment: Looks like overfitting. Explain the DNN design. How many layers? Which types of layers? In which layer are you using dropout?

Comment: it goes from 90%+  to 76% can it be overfitting

Comment: Yeah, looks like overfitting. The accuracy is from a test dataset right? Are you using dropout on every hidden layer? Your network has 6 layers? (input, 4 hidden and output)

Comment: Yes dropout on every layer. its validation accuracy while training the dataset i.e prediction on samples not given for training

Comment: How many classes and images of each class do you have? Are they ordered by class or are they mixed? Sorry by all the questions but I'm really confused. Dropout should avoid overfitting, but looks like the model is overfitting.

Comment: No problem, I am confused as well :-) there are 2 classes, and they are all mixed. Infact I permute for each batch of training. This is happening after around 44 epoch (i.e 44 full round training)